# using asm (java bytecode) classreader on a class outside of my project packages?

Tags: java, inputstream, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I'm getting by input the path of a class (lets say "C:\Temp\Test.class). What i'd like to do is to intialize a ClassReader to this class and start instrumentation it using ClassAdapter and ClassWriter ( i know how to do the instrumentation).

What I dont know- is how do I "fecth" that class into class reader?

I tried using the constructor  ClassReader(String)  but it was in vain

thanks ! (and sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the library you're using — apparently it's [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). Anyway I see that [the constructor you're trying to use](http://asm.ow2.org/asm30/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#ClassReader%28java.lang.String%29) does not take a file name, but the fully qualified name of a class. However, there's [another constructor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm30/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#ClassReader%28java.io.InputStream%29) that takes an InputStream. So you must be able to solve your problem passing a [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) to this constructor:

```
ClassReader r = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream(filename));
```